# Bulk import of magento (community 1.8) product images

Tags: magento-1.8, php, import, magento-community

I have been working on setting up a new magento store and have found problems when bulk importing images through a csv file. I have set up the dataflow profile for importing images. The products have been importing fine but the images were first giving a ""sku" is not defined error" which was easily fixed but now they are repeatedly giving the two errors "Image does not exist." and "Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"".
[image: Image Errors]
[image: Image CSV file layout]

I need to add multiple images for each product I have currently been doing this by just adding a new line with the SKU and image path but as no images are uploading I don't know whether this is the correct way to go about it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can see one row doesn't have sku, you can't keep the sku empty for any product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot import multiple images using the standard magento dataflow.

You can use magmi tool.

This is a free tool that is very very fast and also allow you to import the catalog media library

You can find this tool from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/)

Comment: Does magmi safe or not

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned here already you cannot import multiple images with the standard CSV import profile. You will have to use some 3rd party tool to upload product images if you have more than one per product.

There is a [Bulk Images Upload & SEO extension](http://extensions.activo.com/bulk-images-for-large-catalogs.html) that allows to mass import thousands of product images in one click matching image files to product SKU. This is probably the easiest way to import multiple images per product.

Alternatively you can also use [Magmi Image Attributes Processor](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor), but you will have to spend some time learning the pretty elaborate Magmi syntax.